# Is it possible to cover images from an api over full-screen?

Tags: html, css, api

I'm trying to center and cover an image up the whole screen which is coming from the [Unsplash Source API](https://source.unsplash.com).

I think because the image actually gets fetched after the CSS is already applied it doesn't work just like that:

(If the demo might appear covered up run it in full-screen)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 .centered-image {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1228371) no-repeat center center fixed;
 }
```

```html
<div class="centered-image"></div>
```

Do you guys know a work-around?

Comment: "I think because the image actually gets fechted after the css is already applied it doesn't work just like that" — No.  Existing CSS is applied to new elements added to the DOM. I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: the image is centered here, and still working when i resize the window. Maybe you have other classes applied that interfer, rather?

Comment: No problem here either. The image was still centered. Either in full screen or not

Comment: Sorry I formulated my question incorrectly. I want the background-image to cover up the whole screen

Comment: add these css rules background-position: center; background-size:100%, and give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.centered-image {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1228371);
}
```

Made some CSS Changes. Give this a try.